# Xamarin : Date in string

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new with xamarin, I am facing an issue in my xamarin forms project.
I have a Label inside listview-viewcell, to show time in UI. The date is received as a number like 1510822596449(Java Timestamp). I want to show the date in strings like "n days ago".How can I achieve this?

```
    <StackLayout>
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding createdTime}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>           
    </StackLayout>
```

Anybody please suggest a solution with working code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this with a value converter as well. Converting from ticks (I assume they are ticks) to date time and then formatting it is a simple google "ticks to formatted date time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a class DatetimeToStringConverter and add the following code:

```
   public class DatetimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
      {
    #region IValueConverter implementation

     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

       return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)
            .AddMilliseconds((long)value) // put your value here
             .ToLocalTime().ToString("g");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); 
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then in xaml add the following code at the root of the page:

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:DatetimeToStringConverter x:Key="cnvDateTimeConverter"></local:DatetimeToStringConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

Then add namespace:

```
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Myapp;assembly=Myapp"
```

Then change the label text like this:

```
Text="{Binding createdTime,  Converter={StaticResource cnvDateTimeConverter}}"
```

Keep the createTime type as long in model, otherwise you get invalid cast exception.

Comment: it's working, but getting like 9/28/2009 4:20AM, is there anyway to convert to n days ago

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you could do this with a [ValueConverter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Binding_Value_Converters).

Write a converter similar to this, in your shared code.

```
    public class TicksToDateTimeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (!Int64.TryParse(value, out long ticks))
                return DatTime.Now;

            // TODO you can do a ToString and format it you want here but also in XAML
            return new DateTime(ticks);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // Not needed
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Now in your XAML, declare te value convter like this under the root of your page, I'm assuming it's a `ContentPage`.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:TicksToDateTimeConverter x:Key="TicksConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And don't forget to declare the `local` namespace in your page root like: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp.Namespace"`, which should be the full namespace, without the class name to your converter class.

To finally use the converter in your layout, do this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding createdTime, Converter={StaticResource TicksConverter}}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>           
</StackLayout>
```

Depending on whether or not you return a string from the converter or a `DateTime`, in the latter case you can also format it here in XAML, like so:

```
<Label Text="{Binding createdTime, Converter={StaticResource TicksConverter}, StringFormat='{0:dd-MM-yyyy}'}"/>
```

Or you could choose to do it differently altogether and convert the value inside the model that you bind to the `ViewCell`.

Comment: Adding var ticks = value as long; shows an error: The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('long' is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: if (ticks == null) return; shows another error : An object of type convertable to object is required.

Comment: You're right, wrote this from the top of my head. Let me fix that.

Comment: Also I am confused with adding xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourApp.Namespace" in xaml

Comment: Not to be rude, but please at least try to understand and not just expect copy/paste answers on StackOverflow. In the root of your page you will find more xmlns declarations, just add it there and replace `YourApp.Namespace` with whatever is after `namespace` for your converter class.

For instance if you converter class looks like this: `namespace MyApplication.Converters { public class TicksToDateTimeConverter { ... } }` add `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Converters"` as an attribute to your page.

Comment: I am new to xamarin, for the clarification I ask. What about the errors that I mention

Comment: No problem! Just saying there is enough in this answer to get you started IMHO and discover some more for yourself, but nevertheless I'll gladly help!

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I made the original comment about using a value converter as I had already walked the OP through this in another question. he seems to want just code and does not try to understand.